# How to set a ReferenceProperty using only a Key, not getting the Model

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, referenceproperty

I want to be able to, given the key to a model in the datastore, simply set the referenceproperty without loading the model itself (as I don't need that information).

For example:

```
class Book(db.Model):
    author = db.StringProperty()
    title = db.StringProperty()

class Review(db.Model):
    book = db.ReferenceProperty(Book)
    description = db.StringProperty()
```

Assuming that I already have the key to a `Book` (call it `bookKey`), but I don't have the corresponding `Book` object itself, is there a way to do the equivalent of

```
review = Review()
review.description = "It was ok, but I would recommend it for insomniacs."
review.book = bookKey
```

or do I need to

```
book = Book.get(bookKey) #I don't want this datastore access
                         #as I don't need the book object.
review = Review()
review.description = "It was ok, but I would recommend it for insomniacs."
review.book = book
```

I've found the way to extract the key and ID from the `ReferenceProperty` using `get_value_for_datastore`, but I'm after a "set".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`review.book = bookKey` will work just fine, and set the referenceproperty without fetching the model.

Comment: Thank you.  That's exactly what I needed (that, and to cast the string representation that I had as a Key again).